# Is there any semantic difference between type aliases and interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I have read several guides on the topic type aliases or interfaces. I still don't quite understand the difference. The guides typically conclude with minor technical differences between the two.

Examples of conclusions from articles:

- use interfaces if you need to extend classes, type aliases if you need to use unions
- use whatever suites you and your team, just be consistent
- always use interface for public API's definition when authoring a library or 3rd party ambient type definitions

**But I still wonder**

- Are there any semantic differences between the type aliases and interfaces?
- Is the reason for both of them existing legacy reasons, or is there a place for both concepts in typed JavaScript even 10 years from now?

Comment: An interface is a type without an implementation, essentially.  It has member declarations, but no code implementing those declarations.  Can you see the difference?

Comment: I updated my post to say type aliases instead of types. If your questions still applies, I do fail to see a difference as I can use type aliases as interfaces for my javascript objects